# Stop Safari developer program membership

Tags: safari, developer-program

Does anyone know how to stop Safari developer program membership?

A couple of years ago I enrolled into the program as I was interested in development of Safari extensions. But now I have a really big problem because of this enrollment. Currently I am also a member of iOS development team and **EVERYTIME** when I try to login or just access **ANY** of the sections in the Member Center I need to choose my team

- me as safari developer
- me as member of iOS development team

This is really annoying considering that the Apple's development portal seems buggy because it doesn't remember my choice and keeps asking me to select the team after every single click and redirects me back to the portal home page so I am not able to proceed further.

If anyone knows how to cancel a membership of a certain developer program of Apple, please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply let the Safari membership term run out, as it doesn't look like Apple has given people an easy way to do this. Your best bet at cancelling it immediately though is to call Apple directly at 1-800-633-2152 and ask for them to cancel it.